# Merge Statement throwing error

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have a temp table  -

```
   CREATE TABLE #TempMain(
      A int,
      B int,
      C int
   )
```

I run the following insertion just query once just to populate #TempMain

```
insert into #TempMain 

        SELECT 
                      A,
                      B,
                      C
                FROM dbo.entity where RequestId = 1241 and ClassId = 25 and type=102
```

After that i am using Merge statement -

```
   MERGE #TempMain AS Target
            USING (
                    SELECT 
                          A,
                          B,
                          C
                    FROM dbo.entity where RequestId = 1241 and ClassId = 25 and type=102
                  ) AS Source ON (Target.B= Source.B AND Target.C= Source.C)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET Target.A= Source.A
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN 
            INSERT (A,B,C)
            VALUES (Source.A,Source.B,Source.C);

            select * from #temp1
```

When i run this merge statement query i get an error -

The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

I am not able to understand the problem in my code. i looked for other similar errors i am still not able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to understand the problem in my code.

It is obvious that your data can be not unique by `B, C` in `#TempMain` and of course the same rows exists in `dbo.entity` as well. So, in case of join you will get Cartesian product and  the same row from target (and from source as well) exists more than ones. So this `UPDATE SET Target.A= Source.A` will update same row more than once.

Comment: What condition do you think i should change to get (0 rows effected ) using merge statement as they both have same entries.

Comment: I have no idea of your intention. I strongly answered to you question which is highlighted in my answer. If you have another question read firstly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then create well formed question.